# TSconfig Clear cache options in external file not working in TYPO3 7.6.x

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am including a TypoScript file in the ext_localconf.php of my template extension like this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/TsConfig/User/config.t3s">');
```

I have the following options in config.t3s the file:

```
  options.clearCache.system = 1
  options.clearCache.pages = 1
  options.clearCache.all = 1
```

If i inspect the TSconfig with the Info  module, i can see these setting.
I have alway included the TSconfig like this and it was always working like a charm.
But since TYPO3 7.6.x the Caching Toolbar will not show up for non admins.

If i include the settings above directly in the User settings, the Caching Toolbar is showing up.

Anbody having the same experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the setting to the wrong TsConfig! Use

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addUserTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Configuration/TsConfig/User/config.t3s">');
```

and it should work fine.